# How can I access file properties in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file

This may actually be a 2-part question.

1) How can I access properties of a file (read-only status, creationdate, pretty much anything you can see on the properties screen when you right-click a file and select "Properties") in C#?

Is there a syntax like `file.Attributes["CreationDateTime"]` that will do this?

2) How can I access the target of a .lnk file (a desktop shortcut for instance) using C#?
And I want the entire target, I have ones which look like:

> "[somepath]" "[somepath]" /cmd
>   "somepath"

And I need that entire value.  Current code is giving only the first path.

Comment: I'ld like to take a moment so just sit right there while I tell you all about my friend the `msdn library from microsoft` [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Comment: @drachenstern- I'm aware of this class, but it doesn't seem to have what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object. It has creation time as a property.

I'm not sure what you mean for the second part...

Comment: I think he means on a shortcut for the second part.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to access information about a file that is not a property of the FileInfo object?

Comment: @MAW No, however, you could use the windows scripting host to accomplish this.  Look here. http://www.debugging.com/bug/14827

Comment: I need the target of a .lnk file, but I'd like to be able to get any information about a file.

Comment: @MAW - I've got it now. Take a look at George's link - the "CreateShortcut" is poorly named - it will also open an existing shortcut.

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens- I'm not looking to open the file, just find out information about it (in this case the full path of its target)

Comment: @George- I'd like to give you the answer for this.

Comment: @George - why don't you post an answer with your stuff? I'm at the rep limit for the day anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Chris has answered the first part.

For the second part of your question : You're actually looking to play with [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is native Windows API that is **not** available directly in .NET.

However, someone out there always writes a [reusable library.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2010/12/05/c-ishelllink-com-interop-example.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) I should have a property that gives you the target.

Heres [another library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellify/) I found at [Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut) this one is **recommended** since it is a 100% managed solution, IOW, it does not call COM (something you'd rather not do)

Finally just incase you need the [file format, here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305%28PROT.10%29.aspx). The pdf link doesn't seem to be working, but you can download all revisions I think.

---

Since you're not clear on the first question too, I would be nice if you said exactly **what** information you need from the file (Like when you said you wanted the target)

Like IShellLink, if .NET doesn't provide some API, you have to go native. But usually .NET does provide what you need. Look at this paragraph on the msdn page that Chris has linked to:

> *The FileInfo class provides the
>   following properties that enable you
>   to retrieve information about a file.
>   For an example of how to use each
>   property, see the property pages.*
>
> The [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory.aspx) property retrieves an
>   object that represents the parent
>   directory of a file.
>
> The [DirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname.aspx) property retrieves
>   the full path of the parent directory
>   of a file.
>
> The [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists.aspx) property checks for the
>   presence of a file before operating on
>   it.
>
> The [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx) property retrieves or
>   sets a value that specifies whether a
>   file can be modified.
>
> The [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) retrieves the size of a
>   file.
>
> The [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx) retrieves the name of a file.

Comment: @giddy- this looks good, but is a bit more than I need right now.  I can get the file's target using George's link, which does the trick.  But really good information!

Comment: np! =) Yea George's WSH solution looks awesome, its also much less of a headache, maybe even perf-wise.

Comment: @giddy- I was deliberately vague in the first part, I was hoping to find some way to reference attributes by their String name (my ideal syntax would be file.Attributes["AttributeName"]).

Comment: @Maw74 ah I see.  If its an API requirement or something you could always create a wrapper that exposes an indexer.